# How do you change input parameters of pandas groupby.agg function?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am having issues using the groupby_object.agg() method with functions where I want to change the input parameters. Is there a resource available of function names .agg() accepts, and how to pass parameters to them?

See an example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3], 
               'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'red', 'white', np.nan], 
               'weight': [10, 10, 20, 5, 10, 20]})

df['colors'].nunique() # Returns 3 as NaN is not counted
df['colors'].nunique(dropna=False) # Returns 4 as NaN is counted
```

When I then `groupby` 'colors' how can I pass the `dropna=False` parameter with the function?

```
df.groupby('numbers').agg({'colors': 'nunique', 'weight': 'sum'})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though `pandas` has nice syntax for aggregating with dicts and NamedAggs, these can come at a huge efficiency cost. The reason is because instead of using the built-in groupby methods, which are optimized and/or implemented in cython, any `.agg(lambda x: ...)` or `.apply(lambda x: ...)` is going to take a much slower path.

What this means is that you should stick with the built-ins you can reference directly or by alias. Only as a last resort should you try to use a `lambda`:

In this particular case use

```
df.groupby('numbers')[['colors']].agg('nunique', dropna=False)
```

**Avoid**

```
df.groupby('numbers').agg({'colors': lambda x: x.nunique(dropna=False)})
```

---

This example shows that that while equivalent in output, and a seemingly minor change, there are enormous consequences in terms of performance, especially as the number of groups becomes large.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def built_in(df):
    return df.groupby('numbers')[['colors']].agg('nunique', dropna=False)

def apply(df):
    return df.groupby('numbers').agg({'colors': lambda x: x.nunique(dropna=False)})

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'numbers': np.random.randint(0, n//10+1, n),
                                  'colors': np.random.choice([np.NaN] + [*range(100)])}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: built_in(df),
        lambda df: apply(df)],
    
    labels=['Built-In', 'Apply'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 20)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,  
    xlabel='~N Groups'
)
```

[image]

---

#### But you want to do multiple aggregations and use different columns

The `.groupby()` part of a groupby doesn't really do that much; it simply ensures the mapping is correct. So though unintuitive, it is still much faster to aggregate with the built-in separately and concatenate the results in the end than it is to agg with a simpler dict using a lambda.

Here is an example also wanting to `sum` the weight column, and we can see that splitting is still a lot faster, despite needing to join manually

```
def built_in(df):
    return pd.concat([df.groupby('numbers')[['colors']].agg('nunique', dropna=False),
                      df.groupby('numbers')[['weight']].sum()], axis=1)

def apply(df):
    return df.groupby('numbers').agg({'colors': lambda x: x.nunique(dropna=False), 
                                      'weight': 'sum'})

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'numbers': np.random.randint(0, n//10+1, n),
                                  'colors': np.random.choice([np.NaN] + [*range(100)]),
                                  'weight': np.random.normal(0,1,n)}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: built_in(df),
        lambda df: apply(df)],
    
    labels=['Built-In', 'Apply'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 20)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,  
    xlabel='~N Groups'
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very good explanation and thank you for it. Question based on your answer, ```df.groupby('numbers')[['colors']].agg('nunique', dropna=False)``` this means that the only column aggregated will be ```colors```, and i can change to ```df.groupby('numbers')[['colors','weight']].agg('nunique', dropna=False)``` to get a unique list of both columns. However, what if someone wants to get the ```max()``` on weight column, and ```nunique``` of colors column?

Comment: @sophods ah yeah sorry I was just adding that. You can look at my second example, where I split out the one groupby and then `concat` in the end. If efficiency isn't a huge issue (i.e maybe you have a small df, not one with 20 Million groups) then I'd say readibility might be more important. But in many cases of larger data these slowdowns can be the difference between a 1 minute or 1 hour calculation, so it's often better to take the slightly more complicated coding path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this link
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

and navigate to the "Aggregation" section where you can find the different methods that are available on grouped data.

In your case, you can pass `dropna=False` if you use a `lambda` function:

```
df.groupby('numbers').agg({'colors': lambda x: x.nunique(dropna=False), 'weight': 'sum'})

Out[324]: 
         colors  weight
numbers                
1             2      20
2             2      15
3             2      40
```